# Write into a word document with styles

Tags: java, text, ms-word, apache-poi

I'm writing text from a List into a word document, now is my problem that it goes in without any style/breaks.

Like this :

> test test test test test

But I would like to have it like this :

> test
>
> test
>
> - List item
> - List item

I use the following code to write in to a word document :

```
XWPFParagraph paragraph = nieuwDocument.createParagraph();
              
XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
           
run.setText(gevonden.toString());

nieuwDocument.write(out);
nieuwDocument.close();
out.close();
System.out.println("Klaar");
```

`gevonden.toString() = gevonden` is the list that contains my text.

I have tried the `split()` function but that don't work on a List.

Has someone a suggestion?

**Update**

I did put the function `run.setText()` into a for loop and add the `add.Break()`
But then it writes the text from the List everytime until he leaves the for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < gevonden.size(); i++)
{   
 run.addBreak();
 run.setText(gevonden.toString());
}
```

Output is :

> [test test test test test]
>
> [test test test test test] etc.

Knows somebody how do I get the `i` from the list `gevonden`.
If i try on this way : `run.setText(gevonden[i].toString());` ,

I get the error :

The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List

I think if I get the `i` my problem is solved

Comment: Use a for loop through gevonden and add line breaks (or other styles you need) inside the loop.

Comment: What kind of list is `gevonden` exactly? If [java.util.List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), then read about iterators in collections and the for-each-construct in Java.

Comment: @AxelRichter Its a  `java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: http://crunchify.com/how-to-iterate-through-java-list-4-way-to-iterate-through-loop/

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks for the link, but looping trough the list is going well. The problem is more the output of it into the word document.

Comment: Your code iterates over the List, yes. But you are taking the whole list with List.toString each time  instead of getting the part on which the iterator is currently. The linked example shows 5 methods how to do this right.

Comment: @AxelRichter Much thanks, I didnt read it well the first time I think my bad. Its works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it thanks to Axel Richter

Here is the code :

```
for(int i = 0; i < gevonden.size(); i++)
{   
    run.addBreak();
    run.setText(gevonden.get(i));

}
```

With `gevonden.get(i);` I got the piece of the List instead of the whole list.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html), you can add break by using `run.addBreak()` method and carriage return by using `run.addCarriageReturn()`.

As for the list, I'm not sure, but you might try this:

```
XWPFParagraph para = doc.createParagraph();
para.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
para.setNumID(addListStyle(abstractNum, doc, numbering));
para.getCTP().getPPr().getNumPr().addNewIlvl().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf( your_indent_level));
```

I think you might need to loop on the contents of gevonden and add it on their respective levels. I have never used xwpfrun, but I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to list an item in next line,try to add a '/n' or '/r' when you get an item